# "...but this assumption, however it is motivated, is only realistic"

Tags: meaning

I don't understand the meaning of the second part of [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=G1MJLmn5QpYC&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=%22we+need+to+assume+that+parties+cannot+move+freely+across+the+policy+space%22&source=bl&ots=Lb9RQOvFb6&sig=yxv1s2-ifANH1HRFINNokCYFObg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oBDuUq3zJIumsQSM2ICgAg&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22we%20need%20to%20assume%20that%20parties%20cannot%20move%20freely%20across%20the%20policy%20space%22&f=false) sentence. It seems paradoxical.

> To understand what will happen in such cases, we need to assume that parties cannot
>   move freely across the policy space *but this assumption, however it is motivated, is only realistic.*"

Answer (score 2):

"To understand what will happen in such cases": we are attempting to understand something...

"we  we need to assume that parties cannot move freely across the policy space": in order to understand this thing we have to take something for granted (assume something)

"but this assumption": we are about to describe this assumption we need to make

", however it is motivated,": (irrelevant) regardless of the purpose for the assumption we will need to make

"is only realistic.": the assumption we are about to make is reasonable, and not something we should feel panicking about because it IS realistic and thus perhaps not an assumption, but closer to a fact. (the use of the word 'only' here may be confusing: it emphasises that it is in fact realistic)